# How to check if a driver is signed with a revoked certificate using Windows APIs?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-kernel

In the latest version of Windows, `NtLoadDriver` now returns `status_image_cert_revoked` when trying to load drivers with revoked certs.

My question Is how can we do the same check on a driver file and see if It's signed with a revoked cert?  We tried to use `WinVerifyTrust` similar to how VerifyNameTrust from Microsoft samples is using it:

```
WINTRUST_DATA wtd = { 0 };
WINTRUST_FILE_INFO wtfi = { 0 };

wtd.cbStruct = sizeof(WINTRUST_DATA);
wtd.pPolicyCallbackData = NULL;
wtd.pSIPClientData = NULL;
wtd.dwUIChoice = WTD_UI_NONE;
wtd.fdwRevocationChecks = WTD_REVOKE_WHOLECHAIN;
wtd.dwUnionChoice = WTD_CHOICE_FILE;
wtd.pFile = &wtfi;
wtd.dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY;
wtd.hWVTStateData = NULL;
wtd.pwszURLReference = NULL;
wtd.dwProvFlags = WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT;

wtfi.cbStruct = sizeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO);
wtfi.pcwszFilePath = pwszFileName;
wtfi.hFile = NULL;
wtfi.pgKnownSubject = NULL;

//
// Check the file's Authenticode signature
//

if (S_OK != WinVerifyTrust((HWND)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, &wvtProvGuid, &wtd))
{
    lastError = GetLastError();
    goto Cleanup;
}
```

but it doesn't return a revoked status. `SigCheck` from sysinternals doesn't return revoked either, but when I try to load the driver it says that the certificate is explicitly revoked. So which windows API do I need to use to get a revoked status in return?

Comment: Note that the return value from WinVerifyTrust should be used directly, not call GetLastError. And according to the docs that return value is not actually an HRESULT (despite earlier versions of the docs apparently saying that).

Comment: Applications can use the Windows Media Format SDK, version 9 or later to get the [certificate revocation list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/certificate-revocation-lists) (CRL) for revoked drivers. Or use [X509ChainStatus Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatus?view=net-7.0) to get the revocation flag.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Correct, but the return from WinVerifyTrust is just S_OK, so no errors in case of these revoked certs.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I tried the sample code from there, but QueryInterface gives the following Error : 0x80004002 - No such interface supported

Comment: Try [CertVerifyRevocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certverifyrevocation) function. Also see [Certificate Revocation List Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-functions#certificate-revocation-list-functions)